# Setting Combobox Value With VBA MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to make a module to pass a single result of a query into a Combobox to be populated/displayed immediately on Form_Load event, but I keep getting the following error: **Run-time error '2465' "Microsoft Access can't find the field 'MyCombo' referred to in your expression"**
Query result is tested and returning the proper value. the problem is in the reference call to the MyCombo combobox.

This is my code below:

```
Public Function getSetRefNo() As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    
Dim currentformName As String
currentformName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
Dim docidrefnoquery As String
Dim dociddefaultvalue As String
      
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM TblA WHERE ColC = " & Forms(currentformName)![Combo25])
    
Do Until rs1.EOF = True
    docidrefnoquery = rs1(0)
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing

dociddefaultvalue = DLookup("RefNo", docidrefnoquery) 'RefNo here is the target column in the Query

Forms(currentformName)![MyCombo] = dociddefaultvalue 'MyCombo here is the Combobox Name
Debug.Print docidrefnoquery & " - " & dociddefaultvalue
End Function
```

on the targeted form, I use this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call getSetRefNo
End Sub
```

after opening the targeted form, I receive the above mentioned error. I don't know what's wrong I tried to trace everything and it seems to be fine, I used the same chunk of codes in other places and worked fine. don't know what's wrong here to be honest. I would be grateful if you could help me elaborate what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to alter the form_load event like the following:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.TimerInterval = 30
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
Me.TimerInterval = 0
Call getSetRefNo
End Sub
```